# How to choose closer gaussian?

Tags: gaussian-mixture-distribution

Suppose, I have two random number generators with normal distribution, which generated a number. How to decide, to which one it is most probably belong?

[image]

Should I calculate probability density of each an compare?

Or I can meausure distance in sigmas and compare?

Or it is the same?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the distribution parameters of your two number generators: to guess which generator it was more likely to have come from, just plug the sampled number into their pdfs, and pick the one with the larger pdf.

This assumes that your number generator was equally likely to draw from either distribution.

Comment: Can't I measure this distance to centers in sigma units?

Comment: You should check this by computing the likelihood ratio. Does $\left( \frac{x-\mu_1}{\sigma_1} \right)^2 < \left( \frac{x-\mu_2}{\sigma_2} \right)^2$ imply $f_1(x) > f_2(x)$ ? $f_1$ here is the pdf of a Gaussian with mean $\mu_1$ and variance $\sigma^2_1$; similarly for $f_2$.

Comment: I am trying to calculate this and gettin "NO" answer. But I saw often in literature, that number of standart deviations discussed.